# java how to stop loop and get the value of counter

Tags: java, loops, counter

I'm just stuck in here for an five hours, I just want to get value of info which is counter and start from zero but when the given condition met I just want to get the value of counter. is there any
better and simple way to get this?
my code below:

```
for(int info = 0; info<currentData.length();info++ ) {
    JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(currentData.length() - 1);
    long getcurrenttime = managedata.getLong("dt");

    while (getcurrenttime > currentEpochTime) {
        // i want to get the 'info' value here when the following condition meet.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
for(int info = 0; info<currentData.length();info++ ) {
    JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(currentData.length() - 1);
    long getcurrenttime = managedata.getLong("dt");

    if (getcurrenttime > currentEpochTime) {
        // i want to get the 'info' value here when the following condition meet.

        System.out.println(info);
        // make info=0 if you want to start the loop again from begining
        // else use break to break the for loop when condition is meet

        // Use this 
        // info = 0

        // or this  depending on your usecase
        //break
    }
```

Comment: thanks but now helping, i just want to get the value of info where it stops, it will print all the value of info from zero.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a variable before for loop to store the info value from loop as below :

```
//some method
int storedInfo=0;
for(int info = 0; info<currentData.length();info++ ) {
    JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(currentData.length() - 1);
    long getcurrenttime = managedata.getLong("dt");

    if (getcurrenttime > currentEpochTime) {
        // i want to get the 'info' value here when the following condition meet.
        storedInfo=info;
        //you can break further looping as condition met and you have stored info value above
       break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just break when the condition metches. I'd introduce also a boolean so I know if the condition matched at least one time:

```
int info = 0;
boolean conditionMatch = false;

for(int info = 0; info<currentData.length();info++ ) {
    JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(currentData.length() - 1);
    long getcurrenttime = managedata.getLong("dt");

    while (getcurrenttime > currentEpochTime) {
        // i want to get the 'info' value here when the following condition meet.
        conditionMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(conditionMatch){
    System.out.println("Condition matched when counter was:" + info);
else{
    System.out.println("Condition not matched");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
    int info = 0;
    for(; info<currentData.length();info++ ) {
        JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(currentData.length() - 1);
        long getcurrenttime = managedata.getLong("dt");

        if (getcurrenttime > currentEpochTime) {
            // i want to get the 'info' value here when the following condition meet.
           break;

        }
   }
   if(info != currentData.length()){
      System.out.println(info);
   }
```